# Specify a login only template in Ember

Tags: ember.js

Is there a way in EmberJS to have a separate template for login that doesn't render the rest of the application template? Ideally I would like to create a login component, but I can't figure out how to render it on the `login` route without it being wrapped in the application template.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there isn't. There might be some very clever hacks, but there's no way out of the box. However, I had the same problem and solved it using a simple if statement. You can use the `currentRouteName` property to get the current route name, which allows you to do something like this:

Application Controller

```
isLoginRoute: Ember.computed('currentRouteName', {
    get() {
        return (this.get('currentRouteName') === 'login');
    }
})
```

Application Template

```
{{#if isLoginRoute}}
    {{outlet}}
{{else}}
    <div>
        <span>Some content</span>
        {{outlet}}
    </div>
{{/if}}
```